# possible numbers from given numbers using permutations and combinaitions

Tags: permutations, combinations

I know this may be trivial, But i searched google and stackexachange to find the solution or the method to find the solution.

The problem in hand is I am given a number say "12345" and I should find out all possible 5 digit numbers using 1,2,3,4,5 and only 5 digits not 4 or less digits. so we have 5! values here. But If i have repeated numbers like say "11234" or "11223" then how to solve it. If there is a 0 in the given numbers then initial 0 is in valid.

Any help in finding the formula for this please? (I have learnt some 12 years ago.. so dont recollect permutations and combinations exactly to solve it myself)

PS: My numbers will never range from (0-9) it will always the digits given in the original number

Comment: How about $5^5$? There is a different answer when $0$ is included and not allowed to come first. At present, it is not clear whether or not your question refers to this scenario.

Comment: @barakmanos 5^5 is not answer, as we have to use the digits, the same number of times, in the given number. so in 11223, we can use 1 twice and 2 twice and 3 only once. so , for 11223, 12123 is valid number

Comment: How exactly is the digit $3$ used the same number of times as the digit $2$ in the number $11223$?????

Comment: If you're asking about the number of permutations when digits may appear more than once, then for a number like $\color\red1\color\red1\color\green2\color\green2\color\orange3$, the number of permutations is $\frac{5!}{\color\red2!\cdot\color\green2!\cdot\color\orange1!}$.

Comment: @barak manos , 12123 has 2 ones, 2 twos and 1 three like in the original number 11223. (order or arrangement of numbers is not important.) so 11223 can take any of the below values and some more as well  11232,11322,12231,12213 etc. Basic Idea is to rearrange the number and form 5 digit numbers. Hope I am clear now.

Comment: The general formula is $\frac{(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}c_k)!}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}(c_k)!}$, where $n$ is the total number of different symbols and $c_k$ is the number of times that symbol #$k$ occurs. For example, the number of permutations of $556667777$ is $\frac{(2+3+4)!}{2!\times3!\times4!}$. Again, if $0$ is one of the symbols **AND** not allowed to come first, then this formula requires some modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of different strings of length 5 from the alphabet $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is what you want to calculate. There are $5^5$ such strings, as each element of the string can be chosen in 5 different ways and you then apply the ["rule of product"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product).

However, you then mention that, "If there is a 0 in the given numbers then initial 0 is [invalid]." Now, this is not really the same question. You said you were given the alphabet $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. If this is actually the case, you wouldn't have to worry about zeros. Then again, if you did have the alphabet $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ instead, then you would have to deduct the strings of types "0xxxx","00xxx","000xx","0000x", and "00000" from $6^5$ which would be the total number of strings. I will let you figure out how many strings of type "0xxxx", etc. there are.

**EDIT:** The question is somewhat unclear but I notice, from the discussion in the comments above, that you are not looking for selections with repetition (?). In that case, I believe what you are looking for is a formula, also given by barak manos in the comments above, namely $\dfrac{5!}{2!2!1!}$ for "11223" for example.

To derive this, you have to realize that $5!$ is first how many ways we can permute five elements. Then, if you see the two '2':s as different, you can permute them in $2!$ ways, the '3':s in $2!$ ways, and the '1':s (trivially) in $1!$ way. The formula is then to divide the total number of permutations ($5!$ in your case) with the product of all the ways you can permute each set of elements that are "the same" (the '2':s and the '3':s in the example).

Ex. How many words can we create from "BANANA"? Answer: $\dfrac{6!}{3!2!}$ (omitting the $1!$).

Hopefully I have interpreted your question correctly, otherwise, please make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you @Barak monos and Chistopher.L for your help.